# Angular 1 With Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, gulp, gruntjs

I'm looking into creating an app with typescript and angular 1.6.0. But everywhere I look is using webpack, babel, grunt, gulp, there is no single consensus on which is the best way to proceed with an app like this.

Anyone got any hints?

Thank you.

Comment: You will probably have better luck asking about the specific technologies and when you'd want to use each one. Of the technologies you listed, only grunt and gulp really compete with each other. It's totally reasonable to have a webpack + babel + gulp project, for example.

Comment: Also, this kind of advice is not in the scope of SO. Try other platforms like Quora. If you have a specific issue that you can't solve we can help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a specific need for using angular 1.6.0? As opposed to creating an angular2 project?

You can get more information here: [Angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/)

Angular cli currently includes webpack and you will not need to use gulp or grunt at all. In addition to the angular cli bundling your app together it allows easy build for Ahead of Time Compilation and tree shaking. Having these two features is nice for when you are ready to deploy your application to a production server you can bundle the application into a small package and serve a small amount of JS files.

Using the angular cli also helps you to code with best practices within an angular2 application. You generate new components/directives/pipes with a simple `ng generate [component] [name]` command.

I would strongly suggest reading through the angular quickstart for ts guide located here: [Angular-Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Also, if you do not want to generate your own projects using the angular-cli. There are various templates online that you can start your application with.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to start from scratch, then why not [Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) ?

My suggestion is Typescript2 + Angular2 with webpack. As stated by @Andy [Angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) is good to go.